# How to get distinct values from PyMongo with selected fields?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In MongoDB I have a dataset of University data. I need to get only distinct name and sourceURL, My collection contains:

`dict_keys(['_id', 'name','univ_id','sourceUrl'])`

Using PyMongo I am able to get distinct/unique URLs by using:

`data = data_col.find({"univ_id": "glaacuk"}).distinct('sourceUrl')`

and I am able to get  name and sourceURL (but not distinct values)by using:

`data = data_col.find({"univ_id": "glaacuk"}, {'sourceUrl': 1, 'name': 1, '_id': 0})`

I have tried using `data = data_col.find({"univ_id": "glaacuk"}, {'sourceUrl': 1, 'name': 1, '_id': 0}).distinct('sourceUrl')` to get only distinct name and sourceUrl, but it didn't worked.

How can I get only distinct name and sourceURL ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get distinct values on a single column you can use [`.distict()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct).

To get distinct values on multiple columns use [`.aggregate()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) with a `$group` stage.

Example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

collection = MongoClient()['mydatabase']['mycollection']

collection.insert_many([{'name': "a", 'age': 23},
                        {'name': "a", 'age': 23},
                        {'name': "a", 'age': 24},
                        {'name': "b", 'age': 23},
                        {'name': "b", 'age': 23},
                        {'name': "b", 'age': 23}])

for record in collection.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': {'name': '$name', 'age': '$age'}}}]):
    print(record)
```

prints:

```
{'_id': {'name': 'a', 'age': 24}}
{'_id': {'name': 'a', 'age': 23}}
{'_id': {'name': 'b', 'age': 23}}
```

(Use a `$project` stage to pretty that up if needed)

Comment: I tried using:


`for record in data_col.aggregate([{"$match": {"univ_id": "glaacuk"}},
                                  {'$group': {'_id': {'sourceUrl': '$sourceUrl', 'name': '$name', 'courseLevel': '$courseLevel'}}}
                                  ]):`


But still, I am getting duplicate values. Any suggestions?